# focus on two items in the same screen

Tags: blackberry, focus

Hi I have three items in the screen: Button 1, list2 and Button3 I want when I click on button 1 and then to the list, the button 1 still focused and I obtain focus in the items of the list and the button 3 not focus. Is that possible get fosus for two fields in the same screen?
If is possible how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I have one Idea take two buttons for button1 like the images below.assign the handler for button1 as before click & after click.before click[image]

[image: after click]

Comment: Active button list will display in ur list field